# A secure method for changing an EMail

Tags: security, email, web

I'm creating a forum, and currently trying to decide the most secure method for a user to change their EMail.

I figured it might be best to send a confirmation email to the old address, and once confirmed(*after clicking the link in the EMail*), their old EMail address will be replaced by their new address.

But I noticed some sites,

Comment: You didn't finish your question.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring verification from the old email address is a definite boost to security, and should be required for critical sites like banking or high-profile social networking where a hijacked account can do serious damage, but it means users cannot change their email address if they lose access to their email account.

If you're creating a web-forum, then this probably isn't important enough to warrant an explicit release, and there are going to be many users that abandon a forum, let their email address expire, and then return. For this case I advocate simply sending a notification email to the old email address and including an "I didn't request this, please revert my email address immediately" link, that way in case of a hijacked account the original account-holder is still able to reclaim the account, while not inconveniencing those who genuinely no-longer have access to their old email accounts.